# How do send keystrokes if a computer setting does not allow?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a VB.net program to help me fill the properties form in my Solidworks Model. My program uses pixel by pixel comparison to find out where should fill the information and then send keystroke to fill the properties form.

My program works in my home computer. However, it does not work in my company computer. I found out that my company computer does not run "SendKeys.Send". Is there anyway to get around it?

Comment: Don't try to circumvent security measures.  That makes your program malware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I was trying on a school computer try to make a game. I would bother tying to get around it *"That makes your program malware. – jmcilhinney"*
Your company computer has security measures for a reason. Don't try to by pass them **ever**!